# How do we deploy a project in Nimbella to any of the public cloud platforms?

Tags: serverless, cloud-platform

As per my knowledge Nimbella is a serverless cloud platfrom which allows a developer to deploy their application in any public cloud platform since it has a cloud agnostic nature and thereby avoid vendor lock-in.

"Nimbella is cloud-agnostic and can run on public and private clouds thus naturally supporting a hybrid or multi-cloud strategy. As a developer, you can code once and run on all clouds or your local machine, because you can deploy the Nimbella platform anywhere." -(from Nimbella official document.)

So my question is,I didn't see any area which connect the application in Nimbella with any of the public cloud services. How can we deploy the application in Nimbella in any of the public cloud services(AWS,Firebase)?

Answer (score 0):

Nimbella's serverless functions are powered by Apache OpenWhisk ([github](https://github.com/apache/openwhisk), [web](https://openwhisk.apache.org/)) which makes it possible to run your serverless code on any cloud that is powered by OpenWhisk - in addition to Nimbella, there are other cloud providers that offer OpenWhisk as a service: [IBM](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=openwhisk-about) and [Adobe I/O Runtime](https://www.adobe.io/apis/experienceplatform/runtime.html). There is also a ["Nimbella lite"](https://marketplace.digitalocean.com/apps/nimbella-lite) Digital Ocean droplet. Nimbella can be deployed on-prem or a cloud of your choice but this is currently offered as an enterprise feature.

Serverless functions for OpenWhisk have one of the purest function signature: `JSON dictionary -> JSON dictionary`, and the programming model is consistent across languages supported by the project. Additionally, one can run a Container as a function, so that it less necessary for a developer to make a distinction between function and container. The programming model for serverless functions developed for OpenWhisk make them highly portable as well.